# iPhone Memory management for a deallocated password (Malloc Scribble in production?, fill with zeroes deallocated memory?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, c, security

I'm doing some research on how iPhone manage the heap and stack but it's very difficult to find a good source of information about this. I'm trying to trace how a password is kept in memory, even after the `NSString` is deallocated.

As far as I can tell, an iPhone will not clear the memory content (write zeros or garbage) once the release count in ARC go down to 0. So the string with the password will live in memory until that memory position is overridden.

There's a debug option in Xcode, `Malloc Scribble`, to debug memory problems that will fill deallocated memory with `0x55`, by enabling/disabling this option (and disabling Zombies), and after a memory dump of the simulator (using `gcore`) I can check if the content has been replaced in memory with `0x55`.

I wonder if this is something that can be done with the Apple Store builds, fill deallocated memory with garbage data, if my assumption that iPhone will not do that by default is correct or not, or if there's any other better option to handle sensitive data in memory, and how it should be cleared after using it (Mutable data maybe? write in that memory position?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there's something that can be done on the build settings level. You can, however, apply some sort of memory scrubbing yourself by zeroing the memory (use `memset` with the pointer to your string).

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me to the right direction, I found some useful information about this

Comment: @pablobart The problem is that there may be intermediate instances of the NSString data. The only way to really be sure is either use byte arrays and clear after use or subclass `NSString`. If you subclass `NSString` one thing that you have to do is manage the memory which is exactly what you want to do. If you are using GUI elements for password input there is another potential copy left around.  There is no really good way to handle secure strings, many of us have created bug reports asking for a secure `NSString` implementation, please do so as well.

Answer (score 0):

As @Artal was saying, `memset` can be used to write in a memory position. I found this framework ["iMAS Secure Memory"](https://github.com/project-imas/memory-security) that can be useful to handle this:

> The "iMAS Secure Memory" framework provides a set of tools for
>   securing, clearing, and validating memory regions and individual
>   variables. It allows an object to have it's data sections overwritten
>   in memory either with an encrypted version or null bytes

They have a method that it should be useful to clear a memory position:

```
// Return NO if wipe failed
extern inline BOOL wipe(NSObject* obj) {
    NSLog(@"Object pointer: %p", obj);
    if(handleType(obj, @"", &wipeWrapper) == YES) {
        if (getSize(obj) > 0){
            NSLog(@"WIPE OBJ");
            memset(getStart(obj), 0, getSize(obj));
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"WIPE: Unsupported Object.");
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: There is an assumption that you have a valid pointer to the memory, that it is contiguous memory and that the full length is known.

Comment: @zaph is there any scenario where a `NSString` content won't be stored in contiguous memory? If you check the method `getSize` and `getStart` that the iMAS framework is using https://github.com/project-imas/memory-security/blob/master/IMSHandler/IMSMemoryManager.m it seems that they are getting the full lenght and skipping the headers of the NSString object

Comment: That may be or not. I certainly would not bet that the internal `NSString` will not change particularly in light of the issues with multiple code units of UTF-16 , Swift is handling this much better than Objective-C. Then there is the issue of how does `NSMutableString` handle adding characters, if there is an increase in size required will there be an old copy left behind or will there be a noncontiguous allocation for the added characters? We seem to know that other foundation data-based classes use noncontiguous allocations. If one is going for security one must not guess.